# SSRS Row Limit Only With Co-Located Data/Report

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I've got a 2010 farm with reporting services running in integrated mode (trusted account). On that farm, I've got a report in a site collection that queries a list with more than 2000 items. When running the report from the site collection that contains the list, I get the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot read the next data row for the dataset .
>   (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow) For more information about this error
>   navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable
>   remote errors

Here's where it gets, well, odd:

- If I run this report in BIDS 2008, it works perfectly.
- If I run this report from another site collection in the farm (same report, same
  data connection), it works perfectly.
- If I browse to the report on the report server and run it, it works perfectly.
- If I reduce the number of results to less than 2000 on the host site, the report runs
  perfectly.

It's almost like reporting services is using the API if the report and the data source are in the same site collection (and hitting an API row limit of 2000), and the web service otherwise. This might be corroborated by this [msdn entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#SharePointList), but it just says "either web service or API" with respect to integrated mode providers. Has anyone else encountered this?

*Update:* Adding an explicit rowLimit parameter to the CAML appears to to have no effect:

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>Documents</ListName>
<Query>
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="rowLimit">
        <DefaultValue>9999</DefaultValue>
    </Parameter>   
</Parameters>
</Query>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="DocId" />
    <FieldRef Name="DocumentType" />
  </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

*Update to the update:* This may be resolved by a service pack/CU (test pending).

*SP1 Testing results: This problem is resolved in our farm by applying SharePoint 2010 SP1.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this problem in our farm installation by appyling SharePoint 2010 SP1.